# Flatten Pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flatten

I've been trying to work with the Facebook's Insights API lately. I feel like I'm almost there.

Current issue is; I don't know how to flatten my object properly.

This is an example of how it looks:

```
[{'impressions': '10491',
 'date_start': '2021-01-27',
 'clicks': '52',
 'spend': '265.760003',
 'campaign_name': "campaign_xyz",
 'campaign_id': 'campaign_id_123',
 'ad_name': 'ad_name_xyz,
 'ad_id': 'ad_id_123',
 'account_name': 'account_name_xyz',
 'account_id': 'account_id_123',
 'actions': [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '16'},
  {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '18'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_custom', 'value': '4'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_lead', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase', 'value': '9'},
  {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '4'},
  {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '851'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.1152415498471708', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.209429190307342', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.212840703113383', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.223430212241510', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.255869695824072', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.2923329694560824', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.305990577082762', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.3190323731012244', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.334777727694135', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.394900471810386', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.603817837150091', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.611337039483406', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.701618050398896', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.738774496765904', 'value': '2'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.758364024710917', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.custom.907815113379720', 'value': '1'},
  {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '873'},
  {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '873'},
  {'action_type': 'lead', 'value': '3'},
  {'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '9'},
  {'action_type': 'purchase', 'value': '9'}],
 'date_stop': '2021-01-27',
 'country': 'unknown'}]
```

As you can see, when I create a dataFrame from this, it sends up having actions, with all the action_types in one column.

Like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQIyc.png)

My goal is to have each action type, in their own column.

Like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CIvr.png)

Edit:
Tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
for val in df['actions'][0]:
    df[val['action_type']] = val['value']
df.drop('actions', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

1st convert to dataframe then for convert the action_type dict elemenet to columns.

But it results in all the values being the same, throughout the dataframe:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbsYT.png)

Comment: Can you print the length of your list that you have posted. My solution works when you have one element. But I guess you have multiple values.

Comment: At the moment, len(df) is 154. Each with a set of action_types that should be untested.

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it works now! Appreciate this a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
for val in df['actions'][0]:
    df[val['action_type']] = val['value']
df.drop('actions', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

1st convert to dataframe then for convert the action_type dict elemenet to columns.

---

try:

```
def func(row):
    d = {}
    for i in row:
        d[i['action_type']]=i['value']
    return pd.Series(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df1 = pd.concat([df.drop('actions', axis=1),df['actions'].apply(func)], axis=1)
```

Comment: @SebastianBjørnsen: Can you post screenshot?

Comment: Amazing.

So simple. Thank you very much!

Edit:

Almost there. Now I see that the values for each row in the dataframe are the same.

Comment: @SebastianBjørnsen: Didn't get you. each row having same value?? If you are having multiple row then you may need to groupby and then follow this step. I posted the answer according to the data you have given me. if you are having multiple impressions just groupby then try to add this step. Create custom function and use `apply`

Comment: I just made an edit to the post with a screenshot. Each row is unique and should not be grouped here. Sorry for the confusion, and not explaining that there is multiple rows in the dataframe to begin with.